# PageSpeed Insights wrongly reporting cache policy?

Tags: caching, pagespeed-insights, expires-header

Why is PageSpeed Insights failing the cache policy audit? (I have marked one of the failing resources showing its response headers later):

[image]

These are the response headers for the marked resource:

[image]

The expiration headers at the top of my .htaccess:

```
# Caching einrichten
FileETag MTime Size
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Add expire header for JPG type image on the same rules. like : ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"

Answer (score 0):

We had one year and worked.  I don;t know exact period which tool consider has long time but from https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket/issues/1345 sounds like it is 4 months. May be you can try by increasing.
Having best cache policy might be tough & various from use case. Look your requirement and set it accordingly.  Page insight tool confirms you are setting properly for 30 days in case your use case is to pass audit itself then try 4 months and incrementing till you pass.

Thanks