# Cache policy in htaccess not being heeded to by reporting tools

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, mod-expires

There are many questions out there LIKE this [PageSpeed Insights wrongly reporting cache policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107850/pagespeed-insights-wrongly-reporting-cache-policy)  But none address the issue of simply ignoring the cache policies that are stated by the .htaccess file.  Normally I wouldn't worry so much about this, as our sites paint completely in under 2 seconds and user experience is great.  But Management cares about pretty graphs and reports.

I have the following caching policies:

```
ExpiresActive On

# Images
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

# Video
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType video/m4v "access plus 1 year"

# CSS, JavaScript
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

# Others
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
```

I want to point out one in particular since it makes it easy to point out the problem:

```
ExpiresByType video/m4v "access plus 1 year"
```

If you visit the site and view the headers for said file:

[image: HEADERS]

You can clearly see that the setting is being sent by header and is, thus, properly configured for a 1 year policy.  HOWEVER .. When using Insights, OR Lighthouse individually they both report 30 days:

[image: LIGHTHOUSE REPORT]

Not to mention all the other policies that are transferring properly in the header, but being completely ignored by LightHouse and Insights .. Does anyone have any answer for "why" this is happening?  It's infuriating that even though the headers are obviously correctly sent, Lighthouse ignores them.

I have even tried something like this to no avail:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|mp4|m4v|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

But I don't think that will make a difference, since the headers are, in fact, being sent correctly.

Comment: Minor point, but the response you've highlighted is for `video/mp4`, not `video/m4v` as stated.

Comment: "I have even tried something like this to no avail:" - Are you suggesting that setting `max-age=84600` (ie. 1 day) still reported "30 d" in the tool? NB: `Header` will override `ExpiresByType`.

Comment: M4V is highlighted in both examples ...  I do not see MP4 highlighted -- As far as the other, it's a copy paste typo as well .. Should be `31536000`

Comment: This is really more of a [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) question than SO - may be better asked over there.

Comment: "I do not see MP4 highlighted" - In the screenshot: `Content-Type: video/mp4`. The `ExpiresByType` directive is based on the mime-type of the response, not the file extension (which is indeed `.m4v`). So the directive that actually applies here is `ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"`, not `ExpiresByType video/m4v "access plus 1 year"` as you've stated. But as I said, it is a minor point/inconsistency and doesn't make any difference to the outcome.